# Creating a list from twig controller

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have an ajaxcontroller.php with the following code.

```
   /**
     * @Route("/user_stake_list", name="ajax_user_stake_list")
     */
 public function user_stake_listAction(Request $request, AuthService $authService)
    {

        $get = $request->query->all();
        $result = array(
            "draw" => intval($get['draw']),
            "recordsTotal" => 0,
            "recordsFiltered" => 0,
            "data" => array()
        );

        $authService =$authService;
        if(!$authService->isLoggedIn()) return $authService->redirectToLogin();
        $data = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('App:UserStakeTokenEntity')->ajaxListByUser($get, $authService->getUser());

       foreach($data['results'] as $row) {
            $values = array(
                $row['id'],
                $row['amount'],
         


            );

            $result['data'][] = $values;
        }


        $result['recordsTotal'] = $data['total'];
        $result['recordsFiltered'] = $data['total'];
        

        return new JsonResponse($result);
    }
```

I then pull the data within my template using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){


        var order = {
            settings: {
                ajaxUrl: ''
            },
            init: function() {
                order.initDataTable();
            },
            initDataTable: function() {

                var callBack = function() {
                };

                var dataList = $('#table').DataTable({
                    'responsive': true,
                    'processing': true,
                    'serverSide': true,
                    'ajax': {
                        "url" : order.settings.ajaxUrl,
                        "data" :function(d){
                        }
                    },
                    'columnDefs': [
                        { 'orderable': false, 'targets': [] },
                        { 'searchable': false, 'targets': [] }

                    ],
                    'order': [[1, 'desc']],
                    drawCallback: function() {
                        callBack();
                    },
                });

                $('.content-container').removeClass('has-loading');
                $('.content-container-content').removeClass('hide');
            },

        };

        order.settings.ajaxUrl = '{{ path('ajax_user_stake_list') }}';
        order.init();
    });
</script>
```

I am receiving this error.

```
The "App\Entity\UserStakeTokenEntity" entity has a repositoryClass set to "App\Repository\UserStakeTokenRepository", but this is not a valid class. Check your class naming. If this is meant to be a service id, make sure this service exists and is tagged with "doctrine.repository_service".
```

I do have some other ajax lists which load fine, this is a new function we have added and will be displayed using datatables on the template.

Another error i have come across is

```
Uncaught PHP Exception RuntimeException: "The "App\Entity\UserStakeTokenEntity" entity has a repositoryClass set to "App\Repository\UserStakeTokenRepository", but this is not a valid class. Check your class naming. If this is meant to be a service id, make sure this service exists and is tagged with "doctrine.repository_service"." at /home/#########/public_html/##############/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Repository/ContainerRepositoryFactory.php line 62
```

I have put #### to hide some sensitive data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Symfony4 : entity has a repositoryClass set to "App\Entity\CommentRepository", but this is not a valid class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47858041/symfony4-entity-has-a-repositoryclass-set-to-app-entity-commentrepository-b)